# year-data missing for the date range in two columns in SAS with id

Tags: loops, date, sas, missing-data

I have data in the following format

```
Startdate         perm_id     amount       enddate

01JUL2004   4294970232.    787560      01JUL2009
10AUG2005   4294970232     797880      01JUL2009
31JAN2007       4294970232     4344300     31JAN2012
20JUL2010       4294979802     4206400     06JUL2012
08JUL2011       4294979802     4663890     07JUL2012
```

`

I am trying to obtain the years for all missing years between start_date and end_date for each
perm_id?

So it should look something like below

```
startdate       perm_id         tranche_amount        enddate
01JUL2004   4294970232     787560      01JUL2009
10AUG2005   4294970232     797880      01JUL2009
10AUG2006   4294970232     797880      01JUL2009
31JAN2008       4294970232     4344300     31JAN2012
31JAN2009       4294970232     4344300     31JAN2012
31JAN2010       4294970232     4344300     31JAN2012
31JAN2011       4294970232     4344300     31JAN2012

20JUL2010       4294979802     4206400     06JUL2012
08JUL2011       4294979802     4663890     07JUL2012
```

I have run the following code;

```
`your text`data loansdata;
`your text`select startdate, enddate and perm_id;
`your text`input startdate enddate perm_id date9.;
`your text`want=1;
`your text`do while (startdate <=year<= enddate);
    output;
    date=intnx('year', date, 1, 'b');
`end;
`format perm_id year tranche_amount  date9.;
`run;
```

Appreciate comments;

Regards`

Seb

Comment: I don't understand your rule. Why isn't the first observation repeated 6 times since it starts in 2004 and ends in 2009?

Comment: Hi Tom thanks for reply, tranche amount it cumulative loans taken, hence an annual figure is need until maturity. I need to roll the figure over each year.

Comment: Does not answer the question. And raises a new one.  you appear to want to total something by year? What are you totally? Show examples. Explain the rules for totaling. With examples.  Since I cannot tell what you are doing here is my guess at an example: $105 for year 2005 from record one and $125 for year 2005 from record two totals to $230 for year 2005.

Comment: Loans have been tallied tranche_amount has been tallied in the step before. So the first loan was taken in 2004, then another loan was taken in 2005 and then in 2007.( missed a line in the second table as the amount increases), As you can see by the amount increasing. There is no repayment here ( no subtraction, as we assume repaid at maturity. amount and repayment has been left join with conditions on dates.

Comment: That is a start as it explains what the data is better than just posting a listing.  Now explain what is the process for going from the input to output.  Why is record one not replicated 6 times to cover the 6 years it spans?  Is it because it really should truncate at the time the second record starts instead of its original enddate in 2009?  Or is there some other explanation?  Or is the real problem that you need to fix the previous step that did the tallying so that it tallies by year there?  If so then show the original data.

Comment: There is no data for certain years and firms take loans say in year 1 3 and 7... with a maturity of 3 years 5 years and 3 years. So now assume the loan in year 1 is $100 and year 3 $200 and year 7 $500. You will have $100 borrowed in year 1 2 . In years 3,4,5,6 $200 and in year 7 $700  year 8 9 and10  $600 .

Comment: Sounds like the new loans replace the previous loans instead of being in addition to the original loans?

Comment: In theory it should roll off if they mature and accumulate if maturity date not reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to output one record per year from the input data and then aggregate by ID and YEAR.

```
data have ;
  input startdate :date. perm_id :$12. amount enddate :date.;
  format startdate enddate date9.;
cards;
01JUL2004 4294970232  787560 01JUL2009
10AUG2005 4294970232  797880 01JUL2009
31JAN2007 4294970232 4344300 31JAN2012
20JUL2010 4294979802 4206400 06JUL2012
08JUL2011 4294979802 4663890 07JUL2012
;

data step1;
  set have;
  do year=year(startdate) to year(enddate);
    output;
  end;
  keep perm_id amount year;
run;

proc summary data=step1 nway;
  class perm_id year;
  var amount;
  output out=want(drop=_type_) sum=;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs     perm_id      year    _FREQ_     amount

  1    4294970232    2004       1       787560
  2    4294970232    2005       2      1585440
  3    4294970232    2006       2      1585440
  4    4294970232    2007       3      5929740
  5    4294970232    2008       3      5929740
  6    4294970232    2009       3      5929740
  7    4294970232    2010       1      4344300
  8    4294970232    2011       1      4344300
  9    4294970232    2012       1      4344300
 10    4294979802    2010       1      4206400
 11    4294979802    2011       2      8870290
 12    4294979802    2012       2      8870290
```

If the data is large and performance is an issue then you could do the following changes to improve performance.

Make STEP1 a VIEW instead of DATASET.

```
data step1 / view=step1 ;
```

Use BY statement for PERM_ID, which means the original data must be sorted by PERM_ID.

```
proc summary data=step1 nway;
  by perm_id ;
  class year;
  var amount;
  output out=want(drop=_type_) sum=;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you Tom, but the amount doesn’t need to loop or accumulate. It stays fixed as per column . But you’re going 1 step back without my previous step ?

Comment: For the first id what number do you want for the year 2005? If not the sum from the two loans then what? Do you want just STEP1 with two observations for that year?

Comment: Hi Tom, Just one quick question to add amortization or repayment; it would best to expand after step 1; include maturity in years as a column, and repayment_schedule _per_year= ( amount/ maturity) . Then subtract the repayment schedule from each tranche_amount and then loop?

Comment: If you want to do more calculations put them between the DO and the OUTPUT.  If you want the intervals to be other than calendar years then use an OFFSET variable in the DO look instead of YEAR.  You can use INTCK() to determine times through the loop and INTNX() to calculate the new start dates.

Comment: I added month = month ( start year) to month ( endyear) and have obtained the corrected monyy for start and end . Now I need to loop to obtain all months between start and end date for months .

Comment: `do offset=0 to intck('month',startdate,enddate); date = intnx('month',startdate,offset); .... end;`

Comment: I have the message ''i unclosed do block''

Comment: Start a new question with your current problem.  Make sure to provide details of what you are doing, the code you are running and the lines from the SAS log so the error can be seen in context.

Answer (score 0):

So I run the following for months

```
data loans2;
set loans1;

startyear = input(put(startdate,9.),ddmmmyyyy.);
endyear = input(put(enddate,9.),ddmmmyyyy.);


format startyear endyear DDMMYYN8.; 

run;
```

First format into DDMMYYN8. as loops can't be run when months are; JAN, FEB,MAR ETC.

Then I Run the following;

```
data loans1;
set loans2;
date = Startyear;
do until(date > Endyear);
month = month(date);
output;
date = intnx("MONTH", date, 1, "SAME");
end;
```

format date DDMMYYN8.;
run;